# Integrating Django tutorial example Polls app and django-registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, integration, django-registration

I'm learning Django on Ubuntu 13.04, Python 2.7, Django 1.5, Postgres 9.2, 
Bootstrap 3.0. I'd like to achieve a combination of the tutorial example Polls app with django-authentication.

As my first effort I got the Polls app working from the [Django 1.5 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/). I then installed [django-registration 1.0](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest) and [these templates](https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates) to make it work. I chose that package for authentication as opposed to [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as a result of [my question on authentication framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026916/simplest-django-authentication-package-to-use-as-of-oct-2013).

Now I want to integrate Polls and django-registration to record a set of results per user.  After the poll results have been collected the admininstrator uses Django Admin interface to run a script to analyse the results (e.g. compute some statistics) and send an email to a subset of all users.

I briefly looked at two existing projects that looked like could get me there out of the box.

1. [Light Bird's Questionnaire App](http://lightbird.net/dbe2/questionnaire.html) was too complicated using a custom library of modular class based views. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible, using as much of out-of-the-box Django 1.5 functionality as possible for ease of maintenance and initial design.
2. [Pinax web framework on top of Django](http://pinaxproject.com/), although a great idea, seems to be stuck in dark ages of 2011 with latest code supporting only Django 1.4 and Bootstrap 2.x. Starter projects don't look that useful and documentation isn't flash either.

Based on the above it looks like I'll have to do the integration of Polls and registration manually. At first pass I was thinking roughly the following:

- The poll & choice could be simplified down to just a numeric answer to a question.
- At database level we would need a separate table.
- The primary key would be the userid.
- Each column would store one answer per.
- I'm guessing this would need a `class PollsResults` in `model.py` that would include defining the primary key as `User`, which should exist via django-registration.
- Exactly how to do that and what follows gets a bit hazy to me at the moment.

I'm sure the above is a simple exercise for a Django developer. Could anyone give me some starting hints or even better an existing project that does something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're slightly underestimating the power of using a framework such as django. For example, you don't really need to worry too much about tables in the database or what will be their primary keys, because django's Object Relational Mapper (ORM) takes care of a lot of that for you.

If you want to connect two models (database tables) in django you can use a [foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) like this:

```
class ThingOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ThingTwo(models.Model):
    thing_one = models.ForeignKey('ThingOne')
```

The quotes around 'ThingOne' in my ForeignKey are actually unnecessary because the `ThingOne` model has already been defined, but I like to use quotes anyway because it means your ForeignKeys will also work for models defined below (in your code) the model linking to them.

You therefore just need to add a relationship between your Polls and User models. If one user might have many poll results you should probably use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) instead of a ForeignKey but the principle is the same. That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, Garry, but yes, I've realised you can do this as I described in my steps. It's more about how to glue it all together is what I'm after.